# is there any effective or efficient way to find net position of numbers from a data frame in python

Tags: python, recursion, data-science

I have a multi index df, with column "Turtle"

```
|           |        | Turtle | Net Pos|
|-----------|--------|--------|--------|
|2004-11-04 |09:24   |6       |        |
|           |09:34   |2       |        |
|           |09:44   |0       |        |
|           |09:54   |4       |        |
|           |09:04   |1       |        |
|           |09:14   |2       |        |
|           |09:24   |9       |        |

turtle_factor = 3
base_quantity = 2
```

what I need is the "Net Pos". I couldn't figure out a way to do it elegantly.
what I need is the col Net position using Numpy or Pandas
The data set is huge, and need to use recursion and avoid crash.

### Calculation

6 will be spilt in 6 times 1

1 1 1 1 1 1

first 1 will be multiplied base_quantity, so 1*2

second 1 will be multiplied with the result from first 1 with turtle factor 2*3

third 1 will be multiplied with the result from second 1 calculated multiplied with turtle factor above 6*3

forth one will be multiplied with the result from third 1 calculated multiplied with turtle factor above 18*3 and so on
Summing them at the end to get the result as below for 1st row as 728

```
|           |        | Turtle | Net Pos|
|-----------|--------|--------|--------|
|2004-11-04 |09:24   |6       |    728 |
|           |09:34   |2       |      8 |
|           |09:44   |0       |      0 |
|           |09:54   |4       |     80 |
|           |09:04   |1       |      2 |
|           |09:14   |2       |      8 |
|           |09:24   |9       |  19682 |
```

Comment: watch this, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qk0zUZW-U_M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple formula that maps `Turtle` to `Net Pos`. The calculation can be expressed as a sum of geometric series times base_quantity, yielding the function `f` below.

```
turtle_factor = 3
base_quantity = 2

def f(n):
  return base_quantity * (turtle_factor ** n - 1) // (turtle_factor - 1)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Turtle": [6, 2, 0, 4, 1, 2, 9],
})
df["Net Pos"] = f(df.Turtle)
```

Comment: can you please help on this problem?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70810857/split-geometric-progression-efficiently-in-python-pythonic-way

similar to this, but somehow I am not able to figure out how to solve this.